# Loading a video (mp4) file in android

Tags: android, media-player, mp4, playback

```
     VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "vid.mp4");
     mc = new MediaController(this);
     v.setMediaController(mc);
     v.setVideoURI(uri);
     v.start();
```

An alertbox appears saying that the video cannot be played.Do you have a solution to this .

thanks in advance

Comment: either your uri to the file is faulty or the video file is corrupted please check both the options.

Comment: keep your video file in assets folder and then try to play it.

Comment: Or maybe the video format is not supported.. happens most of the times in earlier versions..

Answer (score 0):

This is a linux filesystem permission issue. The location of the file is solely owned by your application. The [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) service ViewView relies on runs as a different "user" from a file system perspective.

The way I've solved this in the past is to create a custom VideoView extending [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) that takes a [FileDiscriptor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) as it's [data source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.io.FileDescriptor%29).

This side steps the issue by providing a connection to the data the is already open as far as the file system is concerned.

If your feeling frisky you could pull down the [VideoView code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/VideoView.java) from google and add a new setVideoFileDiscriptor method.